# Issue with Optional Parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_mySP]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    -- For inventory table check.
    @DealerID       VARCHAR(50),
    @Certified      VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    -- For fuel value.
    @CityFeatureValue   VARCHAR(50),
    @HwyFeatureValue    VARCHAR(50)

AS
BEGIN
        BEGIN
        SELECT  InventoryID, 
                VIN
        FROM    Inventory
        WHERE   DealerID = @DealerID
                AND Deleted     =   'False'
                AND (IsPending  =   '0'         OR IsPending    IS NULL) 
                --AND (Certified    =   @Certified  OR @Certified   IS NULL)

                AND VIN IN
                        (
                            SELECT      VIN 
                            FROM        FuelPerformance
                            WHERE       (
                                            FeatureTitle = 'Fuel Economy (City)' 
                                            AND FeatureValue = @CityFeatureValue
                                        )
                                        OR 
                                        (
                                            FeatureTitle = 'Fuel Economy (Hwy)' 
                                            AND FeatureValue = @HwyFeatureValue
                                        )
                            GROUP BY    VIN
                            HAVING      COUNT(VIN) > 1
                        )
    END
END
```

I am calling it like :

```
EXEC usp_ListOfVehiclesOnFuelCondition_ForSingleDealer
   '09f5245d' , '', '18', '28'
```

When I am commenting the line

```
 AND (Certified = @Certified OR @Certified IS NULL)
```

it is giving the result, but when this line is there the result is blank.

Any suggestion where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing in an empty string (`''`). That is very different from `NULL`.

Pass in the parameters as *named* parameters (without `@Certified`), or test for an empty string, or pass in a `NULL`.

Named parameters:

```
EXEC usp_ListOfVehiclesOnFuelCondition_ForSingleDealer @DealerId = '09f5245d',
                                                       @CityFeatureValue = '18', 
                                                       @HwyFeatureValue = '28'
```

Passing a `NULL`:

```
EXEC usp_ListOfVehiclesOnFuelCondition_ForSingleDealer '09f5245d', 
                                                       NULL, 
                                                       '18', 
                                                       '28'
```

Checking for `''`:

```
AND (Certified = @Certified OR @Certified IS NULL OR @Certified = '')
```

Comment: Thanks..Makes sense..missed silly thing..Just wondering how the same thing is working for other SPs..

Comment: @James - Are all the optional parameters _last_ in the list for the other SPs? Do the other SPs have guard clauses for empty strings?